# Integrating X3Daudio with XAudio2

Tags: c++, audio, xaudio2

I am currently struggling with implementing 3D positional sound with XAudio2 library.
I somehow managed to got it working when listener's and source's position are exactly 0.0f on all axis. When I move listener or source even a little bit, sound is no longer heard but is still playing. What am I missing here? Thanks :)

```
uint32_t sourceInputChannels = 2;
uint32_t masterInputChannels = 8;

float* outputMatrix = new float[masterInputChannels * sourceInputChannels];

// Listener
X3DAUDIO_LISTENER listener{};
listener.Position = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
listener.Velocity = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
listener.OrientFront = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
listener.OrientTop = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };

// Emitter
X3DAUDIO_EMITTER sourceEmitter{};
sourceEmitter.ChannelCount = 1;
sourceEmitter.CurveDistanceScaler = FLT_MIN;
sourceEmitter.Position = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
sourceEmitter.Velocity = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
sourceEmitter.OrientFront = { 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f };
sourceEmitter.OrientTop = { 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f };
sourceEmitter.ChannelRadius = 2.0f;
sourceEmitter.InnerRadius = 2.0f;
sourceEmitter.InnerRadiusAngle = X3DAUDIO_PI / 4.0f;

X3DAUDIO_DSP_SETTINGS dspSettings{};
dspSettings.SrcChannelCount = sourceEmitter.ChannelCount; // 1

// 8 * 2, OUTPUT_CHANNELS is also present in CreateMasteringVoice
dspSettings.DstChannelCount = OUTPUT_CHANNELS * sourceVoiceDetails.InputChannels; 
dspSettings.pMatrixCoefficients = outputMatrix;

// Calculating
X3DAudioCalculate(g_CealContext->X3DInstance, &listener, &sourceEmitter, X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_MATRIX | 
                X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_DOPPLER | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_LPF_DIRECT | X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_REVERB, &dspSettings);

sourceVoice->SetOutputMatrix(g_CealContext->XMasterVoice, sourceInputChannels, masterInputChannels, outputMatrix);
delete[] outputMatrix;
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question by including the code as [properly formatted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) code segments, [not images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: Should be now properly formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, thanks to [@chuck-walbourn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3780494/chuck-walbourn) I managed to get it working.
The problem was that `X3DAUDIO_EMITTER`'s member `CurveDistanceScaler` was set to **FLT_MIN** instead of some not-so-small value. 
Weird thing is I was following official Microsoft documention [How to integrate X3DAudio with XAudio2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/how-to--integrate-x3daudio-with-xaudio2) and the example code uses **FLT_MIN**, so I do not really understand what is going on.

Comment: I filed a [PR](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/win32/pull/1315) to fix that doc page!

Answer (score 1):

X3DAudio has a lot of parameters, but I'm guessing the problem is that you have a stereo (2 channel) source voice and are trying to use 1 channel DSP settings. You are also passing a number of `X3DAUDIO_CALCULATE_` flags which need more data than you are providing.

You should take a look at the original legacy DirectX SDK XAudio2 samples which are hosted on GitHub. In particular, see [XAudio2Sound3D](https://github.com/walbourn/directx-sdk-samples/tree/main/XAudio2/XAudio2Sound3D).

> You should also take a look at [DirectX Tool Kit for Audio](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK/wiki/Audio).

Also, the `sourceEmitter.CurveDistanceScaler` and `sourceEmitter.DopplerScaler` should generally be 1.0.

***UPDATE***: If SrcChannelCount is greater than 1, then you *must* provide emitter azimuths. I have a helper method in *DirectX Tool Kit for Audio* `AudioEmitter::EnableDefaultMultiChannel` that sets these up based on simple speaker geometry--this is how legacy XACT handled them.

```
// **Note these constants came from xact3d3.h in the legacy DirectX SDK**
//
// Supported speaker positions, represented as azimuth angles.
//
// Here's a picture of the azimuth angles for the 8 cardinal points,
// seen from above.  The emitter's base position is at the origin 0.
//
//           FRONT
//             | 0  <-- azimuth
//             |
//    7pi/4 \  |  / pi/4
//           \ | /
// LEFT       \|/      RIGHT
// 3pi/2-------0-------pi/2
//            /|\
//           / | \
//    5pi/4 /  |  \ 3pi/4
//             |
//             | pi
//           BACK
//

constexpr float LEFT_AZIMUTH = 3 * X3DAUDIO_PI / 2;
constexpr float RIGHT_AZIMUTH = X3DAUDIO_PI / 2;
constexpr float FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH = 7 * X3DAUDIO_PI / 4;
constexpr float FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH = X3DAUDIO_PI / 4;
constexpr float FRONT_CENTER_AZIMUTH = 0.0f;
constexpr float LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH = X3DAUDIO_2PI;
constexpr float BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH = 5 * X3DAUDIO_PI / 4;
constexpr float BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH = 3 * X3DAUDIO_PI / 4;
constexpr float BACK_CENTER_AZIMUTH = X3DAUDIO_PI;

constexpr float c_channelAzimuths[9][8] =
{
    /* 0 */   { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 1 */   { 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 2 */   { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 2.1 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 4.0 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH, BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 4.1 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH, BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH, BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, 0.f, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 5.1 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_CENTER_AZIMUTH, LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH, BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH, BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, 0.f, 0.f },
    /* 6.1 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_CENTER_AZIMUTH, LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH, BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH, BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, BACK_CENTER_AZIMUTH, 0.f },
    /* 7.1 */ { FRONT_LEFT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, FRONT_CENTER_AZIMUTH, LOW_FREQUENCY_AZIMUTH, BACK_LEFT_AZIMUTH, BACK_RIGHT_AZIMUTH, LEFT_AZIMUTH, RIGHT_AZIMUTH }
};

...

emitter.ChannelCount = channels;

emitter.ChannelRadius = 1.f;

emitter.pChannelAzimuths = (channels <= 8)
    ? &c_channelAzimuths[channels] : nullptr;
```

Comment: I've looked through several examples and even on [Microsoft official docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/how-to--integrate-x3daudio-with-xaudio2) they use one source channel in DSP settings.

Comment: And SrcChannelCount in DSPSettings struct depends on if the audio is mono/stereo/etc. right?

Comment: In basic setups, SrcChannelCount is the number of channels coming out of the "source voice" and the DstChannelCount is the number of channels going into the "master voice". See the edit for > 1 channel source emitters.

Comment: All the samples only use 1 channel for three basic reasons: (1) DirectSound only supported mono sounds for positional audio so all those samples stuck with mono wav files, (2) multi-channel audio setups add a bit of complexity and code, and (3) honestly I didn't know much about how multi-channel emitters worked when I wrote a lot of those samples 15 years ago :)

Comment: Thanks for clarification. I sorta figured out that SrcChannelCount should match source voice. So I converted source voice to mono and used different sound. And still after passing azimuths still the same problem. :(

Comment: Okay I somehow managed to debug what is going on. Now the sound is only heard when listener's position and source's position match. So maybe whole calculation is in wrong space?

Comment: Try setting ``CurveDistanceScaler`` and ``DopplerScaler`` to 1.0. If your channel count is 1 (i.e. mono sound), the emitter azimuths aren't used.

Comment: YES, that did the trick. But it is really weird, FLT_MIN use in the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/xaudio2/how-to--integrate-x3daudio-with-xaudio2). Anyway thank you so much!